# how to pass refrence from parent to child in vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I have this code

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <h3 class="text-center">Incomplete task</h3>
        <div class="well" style="max-height: 300px;overflow: auto;">
            <ul id="check-list-box" class="list-group checked-list-box">

                    <li v-for="task in incompleteTasks" class="list-group-item">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="" @click="addToDone">
                        {{task.description}}
                    </li>
              <!-- <li v-for="task in incompleteTasks" v-text="task.description" class="list-group-item">
              <input type="checkbox" class="" /></li> -->
            </ul>
            <br />
        </div>
</div>
```

And My **JS**   Looks like this

```
let data = {
                heading:'Task List',
                tasks :[
                        {description: 'GO to store', completed : false},
                        {description: 'SignUp Page', completed :false },
                        {description: 'Create New team', completed : false},
                        {description: 'Add Entity', completed : false},
                        {description: 'Add WorkFlow', completed : false}
                    ]
            };

new Vue({

  el: '#root',

  data: data,

  methods: {
      addToDone() {

        this.completed = true;
        console.log(this);
      },
  },

  computed: {

      heading() {

        return this.heading;
      },

      incompleteTasks() {

        return this.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed);
      },

      completeTasks() {

        return this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed);
      }
  }

})
```

Onclick of the check box I want to toggle the completed property of the object of that li into `True`

how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you be passing the `task` you want to modify in the method, like this:

```
<li v-for="task in incompleteTasks" class="list-group-item">
   <input type="checkbox" name="" @click="addToDone(task)">
                    {{task.description}}
</li>
```

and in the method, mark it done, like:

```
methods: {
    addToDone(task) {
      task.completed = true;
      console.log(task);
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit an item using index, try this way

```
<li v-for="(task, index) in incompleteTasks" class="list-group-item">
   <input type="checkbox" name="" @click="addToDone(index)">
     {{task.description}}
 </li>
```

In the method:

```
addToDone(index) {
  this.$set(this.tasks[index], 'completed', true);
},
```

Comment: I saw that, I just wanted to tell you could do this using `index` .